# more efficient way to extract lines from a file whose first column matches another file

Tags: python, bash, perl

I have two files, target and clean.

- Target has some 1055772 lines, each of which has 3000 columns, tab separated. (size is 7.5G)
- Clean is slightly shorter at 806535. Clean only has one column, that matches the format of the first column of Target. (size is 13M)

I want to extract the lines of target that has a matching first column to a line in clean.

I wrote a grep based loop to do this but its painfully slow. Speedups will be rewarded with upvotes and/or smileys.

```
clean  = "/path/to/clean"
target = "/path/to/target"
oFile  = "/output/file"

head -1 $target > $oFile
cat $clean | while read snp; do
    echo $snp
    grep $snp $target >> $oFile
done

$ head $clean
1_111_A_G
1_123_T_A
1_456_A_G
1_7892_C_G
```

Edit: Wrote a simple python script to do it.

```
 clean_variants_file = "/scratch2/vyp-scratch2/cian/UCLex_August2014/clean_variants"

allChr_file = "/scratch2/vyp-scratch2/cian/UCLex_August2014/allChr_snpStats"

outfile = open("/scratch2/vyp-scratch2/cian/UCLex_August2014/results.tab","w")

 clean_variant_dict = {}


for line in open(clean_variants_file):

clean_variant_dict[line.strip()] = 0


for line in open(allChr_file):

ll = line.strip().split("\t")

id_ = ll[0]

if id_ in clean_variant_dict:

    outfile.write(line)



 outfile.close()
```

Comment: Use a database? If your data is csv, you could do some sort of union query directly on the files.

Comment: Are the two files in predictable order? If the matching lines are in the same order as the "clean" file, you can do it in a single quick pass through both files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Perl solution would use quite a lot of memory (because we load the entire file into memory), but would save you from looping twice. It uses a hash for duplicate checking, where each line is stored as a key. Note that this code is not thoroughly tested, but seems to work on a limited set of data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($clean, $target) = @ARGV;

open my $fh, "<", $clean or die "Cannot open file '$clean': $!";

my %seen;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    $seen{$_}++;
}

open $fh, "<", $target 
        or die "Cannot open file '$target': $!";    # reuse file handle

while (<$fh>) {
    my ($first) = /^([^\t]*)/;
    print if $seen{$first};
}
```

If your target file is proper tab separated CSV data, you could use [`Text::CSV_XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) which reportedly is very fast.

Comment: If you're going to do minimal error messages, why not just [`use autodie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html)?

Comment: why would a perl soln use a lot of memory? Ive stayed away from perl because of the horrible looking syntax so I cant see why it's worse than python memory wise.

Comment: @Miller In general, I am not too crazy about `autodie`, but yes, this might be a reasonable place to use it. The error messages are minimal because I am lazy: If this was code I would use myself I would embellish them more. So, all in all, yes, you're right.

Comment: @pepsimax Are you saying my code looks horrible? The solution requires a lot of memory because we read a large file into memory. It looks like you do the same in your python solution, which would mean the same thing there.

Comment: it looks good for perl :) And yeah, I do, but I figured you meant it would use more memory than a similar solution in python.

Comment: @pepsimax Nono, it should be similar. I should perhaps have said "This solution". And I know what you mean about Perl code. The way some people abuse the language is sometimes physically painful.

Comment: @pepsimax I should add that I still think a database would be the best way to handle this, and it should not be more difficult than any of the solutions presented here.

Comment: Thanks @TLP, I'm totally sympathetic to laziness for short scripts.  That's one of the reasons why I model the usage of `use autodie` to beginners since they fall prey to poor error checking so easily.  I was just confused as to how to improve your script since it felt potentially like a style choice instead of a bug.  I honestly forgot about the option of just writing out a full error message in my confusion :)

Answer (score 2):

python solution:

```
with open('/path/to/clean', 'r') as fin:
    keys = set(fin.read().splitlines())

with open('/path/to/target', 'r') as fin, open('/output/file', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if line[:line.index('\t')] in keys:
            fout.write(line)
```

Comment: i had syntax complaints about this. is a set better than a dictionary?

Comment: @pepsimax what syntax complaints?

Answer (score 2):

Using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane '
    BEGIN{ local @ARGV = pop; @s{<>} = () }
    print if exists $s{"$F[0]\n"}
  ' target clean
```

Switches:

- `-F`: Alternate pattern for `-a` switch
- `-l`: Enable line ending processing
- `-a`: Splits the line on space and loads them in an array `@F`
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Or as a perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

die "Usage: $0 target clean\n" if @ARGV != 2;

my %s = do {
    local @ARGV = pop;
    map {$_ => 1} (<>)
};

while (<>) {
    my ($f) = split /\t/;
    print if $s{"$f\n"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun, I thought I would convert a solution or two into Perl6.

Note: These are probably going to be slower than the originals until Rakudo/NQP gets more optimizations, which really only started in earnest fairly recently at the time of posting.

- First is [TLP's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725418/tlp) [Perl5 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834960/more-efficient-way-to-extract-lines-from-a-file-whose-first-column-matches-anoth/25835067#25835067) converted nearly one-to-one into Perl6.

  ```perl6
  #! /usr/bin/env perl6
  # I have a link named perl6 aliased to Rakudo on MoarVM-jit

  use v6;

  multi sub MAIN ( Str $clean, Str $target ){ # same as the Perl5 version
      MAIN( :$clean, :$target ); # call the named version
  }

  multi sub MAIN ( Str :$clean!, Str :$target! ){ # using named arguments

      note "Processing clean file";

      my %seen := SetHash.new;

      for open( $clean, :r ).lines -> $line {
          next unless $line.chars; # skip empty lines
          %seen{$line}++;
      }

      note "Processing target file";

      for open( $target, :r ).lines -> $line {
          $line ~~ /^ $<first> = <-[\t]>+ /;
          say $line if %seen{$<first>.Str};
      }
  }
  ```

  I used `MAIN` subroutines so that you will get a `Usage` message if you don't give it the correct arguments.
   I also used a `SetHash` instead of a regular `Hash` to reduce memory use since we don't need to know how many we have found, only that they were found.
- Next I tried to combine all of the lines in the clean file into one regex.

  This is similar to [the `sed` and `grep` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834960/more-efficient-way-to-extract-lines-from-a-file-whose-first-column-matches-anoth/25835086#25835086) from [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus), except instead of many regexes there is only one.

  I didn't want to change the subroutine that I had already written, so I added one that is differentiated by adding `--single-regex` or `-s` to the command line. ( All of the examples are in the same file )

  ```perl6
  multi sub MAIN ( Str :$clean!, Str :$target!, Bool :single-regex(:s($))! ){

      note "Processing clean file";

      my $regex;
      {
          my @regex = open( $clean, :r ).lines.grep(*.chars);
          $regex = /^ [ | @regex ] /;
      } # throw away @regex

      note "Processing target file";

      for open( $target, :r ).lines -> $line {
          say $line if $line ~~ $regex;
      }
  }
  ```

I will say that I took quite a bit longer to write this than it would have taken me to write it in Perl5. Most of the time was taken up searching for some idioms online, and looking over the source files for Rakudo. I don't think it would take much effort to get better at Perl6 than Perl5.

Comment: The `-s` version is slow if there is a large clean input file.